# How to enable php_ldap extension on Windows Server 2012 R2 64?

Tags: php, dll, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to enable the **php_ldap** extension on Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bits).

My environment is Apache 2.4 + PHP 7 ([this version](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.0.10-Win32-VC14-x64.zip))

I've removed the **;** from ;extension=php_ldap.dll in **php.ini**. However I got this error in **error.log**:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\\php7\\ext\\php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

I am using the Dependency Walker to get some extra information about "dependencies" of **php_ldap.php**:

- API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
- EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
- SETTINGSYNCPOLICY.DLL

I've installed different version of  VC Redistributable (2005,2008,2010,2012,2015) and it was useless

Is it possible use the php_ldap on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: What does your `extension_dir` directive look like in your php.ini file?

Comment: extension_dir = "E:\php7\ext" and the php_ldap.dll is there

Comment: Maybe it needs a trailing slash? Have you tried making it: `extension_dir = "E:\php7\ext\"`

Comment: @ChadSikorra trailing slash is not required. It seems that error "module not found" appears even if the module is found but some dependencies aren't (unfortunately it does not mention which dependency is missing)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, copy those DLLs:

- **LIBSASL.DLL**
- **php7ts.dll**
- **IESHIMS.DLL**

to:

- System32
- SysWOW64
- php7
- Apache24/bin

Comment: You could probably just add `E:\php7` to your system path...? Haven't seen needing to copy around IESHIMS.dll like that for PHP to work yet.